# How to sort C# Datatable with empty column values at the end

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, dataview

I have a C# datatable with 1000's of rows. But primary 200 rows have empty values (multiple columns). Filter would happen to those columns as empty values to occupy as last. I want output will happen with in the table or new table with filter but not as linq rows. Please help me out

Pictures speaks more words, refer this for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: You have to sort first for row with data in column or not and then sort by the the rows column value

Comment: using LINQ it would be a simple ```orders.OrderBy(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))``` (or ```string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace```). If you want to order by content as well, simply add a ```.ThenBy``` afterwards. Without LINQ you'd have to implement a custom ```IComparer<string>```. Is that what you wanted or are you referring to something different?

Comment: @MyNameIsDND does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things here that you should consider:

1. "**Empty Value"**: To sort items that followed by empty value columns you need `.OrderBy(s => String.IsNullOrEmpty(s["OrderNo"].ToString()))`
2. "**Order No Format**": To sort custom order number you need to use [`IComparer<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer). As you show in your question I assume the format for `Order No` could be `XXXXX` or `XXXX-XXXX`.

So you need to first `OrderBy` empty values `ThenBy` your custom `IComparer<string>` something like this:

```
public class OrderNoComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        int xFirstValue = 0;
        int xSecondValue = 0;

        int yFirstValue = 0;
        int ySecondValue = 0;

        if (x.Contains("-"))
        {
            xFirstValue = Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(new char[] { '-' })[0]);
            xSecondValue = Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(new char[] { '-' })[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            xFirstValue = Convert.ToInt32(x);
        }

        if (y.Contains("-"))
        {
            yFirstValue = Convert.ToInt32(y.Split(new char[] { '-' })[0]);
            ySecondValue = Convert.ToInt32(y.Split(new char[] { '-' })[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            yFirstValue = Convert.ToInt32(y);
        }


        if (xFirstValue > yFirstValue)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (xFirstValue < yFirstValue)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else //means equal
        {
            if (xSecondValue > ySecondValue)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (xSecondValue == ySecondValue)
            {
                return 0;

            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full example is here:

```
DataTable dtOrder = new DataTable();
dtOrder.Columns.Add("OrderNo");

var dr1 = dtOrder.NewRow();
dr1["OrderNo"] = "";
dtOrder.Rows.Add(dr1);

var dr2 = dtOrder.NewRow();
dr2["OrderNo"] = "569-875";
dtOrder.Rows.Add(dr2);

var dr3 = dtOrder.NewRow();
dr3["OrderNo"] = "569975";
dtOrder.Rows.Add(dr3);

var dr4 = dtOrder.NewRow();
dr4["OrderNo"] = "569865";
dtOrder.Rows.Add(dr4);

var dr5 = dtOrder.NewRow();
dr5["OrderNo"] = "569-975";
dtOrder.Rows.Add(dr5);

var dr6 = dtOrder.NewRow();
dr6["OrderNo"] = "569-875";
dtOrder.Rows.Add(dr6);


var result = dtOrder.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()
                .OrderBy(s => String.IsNullOrEmpty(s["OrderNo"].ToString()))
                .ThenBy(o => o["OrderNo"].ToString(), new OrderNoComparer())
                .ToList();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["OrderNo"]);
}
```

Then the output would be like you expected:

```
569-875
569-875
569-975
569865
569975
```